# How to get text from nested div using xpath in Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: html, xpath

I want to pick text from from a nested div but I am unable to get the text while using xpath as locator. Can anybody help and advise how can I get text from nested div. Code shown below...

```html
<div class=”dijitPopup dijitTooltipDialogPopup” id=”SMGGP_dropdown” role=”presentation” style=”RIGHT: auto; LEFT: SO6px; Z-INDEX: 1000; DISPLAY: none; TOP:S83px; VISIBILITY: visible” dijitPopupParent=”>
 <div tablndex=”-1” title=”” class=”dijitTooltipDialog dijitTooltipABLeft dijitTooltipAbove” id=”SMGGP” role=presentation” style=”WIDTH: 300px; POSITION: ;
TOP: 0px; VISIBILITY: visible” widgetld=SMGGP”>
<div class=”dijitTooltipContainer” role=”presentation”>
 <div class=”dijitTooltipContents dijitTooltipFocusNode” role=”dialog” data-dojo-attach-point=’containerNode”>
Text that needs to be picked</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this. One easy way: Get the element you have the ID for, then find the div within that element, by xpath:

(in C#, but Java is very close to it)

```
var topDiv = _driver.FindElementById("SMGGP");
var div = topDiv.FindElementByXPath("//div/div");
```

Comment: I was following same approach. I was able to locate another div on same page but not for this code segment. This code segment is for help content, where help contents appear when user hover over help icon. Otherwise it is not being displayed. As soon user moves the mouse, content window disappear. I can't locate the help content window using web developer tool. Only way was to check the code. As it has dynamic behavior, so, can this be the reason for div not being located?

Comment: @ambysan generally the hidden divs that pop up on mouseover are loaded but hidden. Is it maybe within another div that is hidden? Maybe look at the page source and try to find the hidden div, and see if you can access it through xpath.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your response. Appreciated. I'll try it again.